# How to remove this sentence using python re module

Tags: python, python-re

I want to remove this sentence when I try to get some information.
'(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})'

So, I tried to this code using the re module, but I can't help it.

```
keywords = '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}) <div class=" pirce.pdf0.92MB  carzip.tistory.com remain)'
cleantext = re.sub('\(', '<', keywords)
cleantext = re.sub('\)', '>', cleantext)
cleantext = re.sub('<ads*[^)]+>', '', cleantext)
cleantext = re.sub('<','(',cleantext)
cleantext = re.sub('>', ')', cleantext)
print(cleantext)
```

--> result : None

I want 'remain' remain after print(cleantext) but I got the result None.
I think re module + grammar run maximum size. how to handle this problem?

thanks first.

I want the words "remain" to remain after print(cleantext)

Comment: To help clarify this, put in your question the exact expected outcome of text.  It sounds like you just want the word `remain` is that right?

Comment: yeah, it's right. I want the words 'remain' after carzip.tistory.com words remain after executing re.sub function.

Answer (score 1):

How consistently is it that you want the last word of this input string? Naively:

```
result = keywords.split()[-1].strip(")")
```

If you *absolutely* must use regex, why not just approach it by removing everything you can:

```
result = re.sub(".* ", "", keywords).strip(")")
```

By way of clarification, the `.*` is *greedy*. It'll replace *everything* up until the *last* space in your input string. That leaves you with `remain)`, the strip at the end cleans it up for you.

-- Edits for comments --

Based on the commentary, it sounds like you just want to drop prefixes. Why not:

```
prefix = "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})"
result = keywords.replace(prefix, "")
# ... Extra manipulations here as necessary
```

For one final regex-based option (if you are certain you have to go this route):

```
result = re.sub(".*?\}\)", "", keywords)
```

This last will give you: `' <div class=" pirce.pdf0.92MB  carzip.tistory.com remain)'`.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. In this problem, in fact there're so many sentence and among them, I want to remove  '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})' this part. but i can't handle it.

Comment: Added another option. IMHO, string manipulation is considerably easier to work with than regex unless you _absolutely_ have to use regex for some reason.

Comment: Thaks..... I try to solve this problem using re moudle. but there're many method to use... thanks a lot. god bless you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You know the number of characters and the position that has the sentence, so using the slicing you can make sub-string from the all text. In this place is explained.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-slice-string